# Matrix Multiplication Commutativity.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Find condition for $a, b, c$ and $d$ such that the matrix $B=
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d \\
\end{bmatrix}$
commutes with matrix $A=
 \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 \\
3 & 4\\
 \end{bmatrix} $

My attempt: Commute means $AB=BA$. I applied matrix multiplication. Then I equated each entry with the corresponding entry in $AB$ and $BA$. I had a system of equations (4 unknowns, 4 systems). My answer Is that $b= 2c/3$, $a=d-c$ with $d, c$ as parameters.

BUT, my solution's manual puts that the answer is $a=d, b=0, c=0$.

I think they are making a mistake. Could someone look if my reasoning is wrong or if I'm just doing a calculation mistake?

Comment: The answer of your solution's manual belongs to the question, which matrices $B$ commute with *all* matrices of size $2$. The matrix $B$ is then a multiple of the identity matrix.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1013850/matrix-multiplication-commutativity-generalization.

Comment: The solution manual is certainly wrong, as the given solution excludes having $B=A$, but clearly that is a valid solution to the commutation problem. More generally taking for $B$ a polynomial (with scalar coefficients) in $A$ always gives a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The linear equation given by $AB=BA$ are as follows
\begin{align*}
3b-2c & = 0,\\
2a+3b-2d & = 0,\\
3(a+c-d) & = 0,\\
3b-2c & = 0.
\end{align*}
If we assume that $3\neq 0$ then we can substitute $d=a+c$ and $b=\frac{2}{3}c$. Then all equations are satisfied. So I think, you are right.