# Matrix Multiplication Commutativity Generalization.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Find condition for $a, b, c$ and $d$ such that the matrix $B=
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d \\
\end{bmatrix}$
commutes with any two by two matrix.

My attempt: Commute means $AB=BA$. I applied matrix multiplication. Then I equated each entry with the corresponding entry in $AB$ and $BA$.

Assume A=
\begin{bmatrix}
e & f \\
g & h \\
\end{bmatrix}

From here, I don't really know what to do anymore. I get an augmented matrix. What does one do with it? How do I generalize this? I understood how to do it for one specific case, but not in general.

Comment: Only scalars: this is sometimes called *Schur lemma* in representation theory.

Comment: I don't understand. What's the link with the scalars?

Comment: Scalar multiples of the identity matrix, I mean.

Comment: So far, I have these conditions:
a=d-(h/g-e/g)c; b=f/gc; c=t; d=s; s,t are elements of R.
How do I go on from there?

Comment: I do not really know how to prove that using the identity matrix.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1013819/matrix-multiplication-commutativity

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

Prove that $B$ should be a scalar matrix i.e. $kI_2$ by writing

$$BE_{i,j}=E_{i,j}B,\quad 1\le i,j\le2$$
where $E_{i,j}$ are the elementary matrices.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
Try some special situations first, like $A=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$, or $A=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$, soon you will find out $B$ must be a multiple of the identity matrix. Then, it will be easy to show that it works for all $A$.

Comment: in my solution's manual, it says that the conditions are:
a=d, b=c=0.How do I find the solution?

Comment: I mean, how do I prove it must be a multiple of the I matrix

Comment: I think I just stated the entire proof clearly. You find the solution $B$ using special cases of $A$ (if $B$ does not work for the special cases, it certainly will not work for all $A$, right?), then prove a=b, b=c=0 works for all $A$.

Comment: Yes but that technique does not generalize. You are just saying that specific matrix B works. I could also say a=b=c=d=0 also works. But that does not generalize.

Comment: Does "a=b, b=c=0" include "a=b=c=d=0"?